# Quantile-Quantile Plot using SciPy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

How would you create a qq-plot using Python?

Assuming that you have a large set of measurements and are using some plotting function that takes XY-values as input. The function should plot the quantiles of the measurements against the corresponding quantiles of some distribution (normal, uniform...).

The resulting plot lets us then evaluate in our measurement follows the assumed distribution or not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile-quantile_plot

Both R and Matlab provide ready made functions for this, but I am wondering what the cleanest method for implementing in in Python would be.

Comment: Have you looked at `probplot`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html

Comment: qqplot and probplots with lots of options: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/graphics.html#goodness-of-fit-plots

Answer (score 131, accepted):

**Update:** As folks have pointed out this answer is ***not correct***. A probplot is different from a quantile-quantile plot. Please see those comments and other answers before you make an error in interpreting or conveying your distributions' relationship.

I think that `scipy.stats.probplot` will do what you want.  See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html) for more detail.

```
import numpy as np 
import pylab 
import scipy.stats as stats

measurements = np.random.normal(loc = 20, scale = 5, size=100)   
stats.probplot(measurements, dist="norm", plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I have seen some dotted confidence lines that narrows at the middle and is like a trumpet in the ends. Can you add these "guide lines" to the plot?

Comment: Ok, but this is a probability plot (a sample vs a theoretical distribution). A qq plot compares two samples. 
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/qqplot.htm
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/probplot.htm

Comment: @RickyRobinson It seems that many sources (including wikipedia) contradict the NIST handbook. Pretty much any other source states that a QQ plot has theoretical quantiles on the horizontal axis, and data quantiles vertically. In any case, the distinction is academic: plotting a sample is essentially the same as using the empirical distribution function. Either way, you're plotting one dsitribution's quantiles against another.

Comment: I agree with @RickyRobinson, this is not the correct answer to this question. QQ plots and prob plots are different even though they both one distribution's quantiles against another.

Comment: From the documentation: "probplot generates a probability plot, which should not be confused with a Q-Q or a P-P plot."

Answer (score 71):

Using `qqplot` of `statsmodels.api` is another option:

Very basic example:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab

test = np.random.normal(0,1, 1000)

sm.qqplot(test, line='45')
pylab.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Documentation and more example are [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen it was deliberately separated from `scipy` to `statsmodels`

Comment: Just a note. Your example draws the line for standard normal distribution. To get a standardized line (scaled by the standard deviation of the given sample and have the mean added) like in @Geoff example, you need to set line='s' instead of line='45'

Comment: +1 for this answer. I think it is important to focus more resources on a single package for statistics. `statsmodels` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 25):

If you need to do a QQ plot of one sample vs. another, statsmodels includes qqplot_2samples(). Like Ricky Robinson in a comment above, this is what I think of as a QQ plot vs a probability plot which is a sample against a theoretical distribution.

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot_2samples.html

Comment: This qqplot implementation does not seem to handle samples with different sizes, which is funny because one of the big advantages of a Q-Q plot is that one can compare samples with different sizes...

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this. Maybe you can improve it. Especially the method of generating the quantiles of the distribution seems cumbersome to me.

You could replace `np.random.normal` with any other distribution from `np.random` to compare data against other distributions.

```
#!/bin/python

import numpy as np

measurements = np.random.normal(loc = 20, scale = 5, size=100000)

def qq_plot(data, sample_size):
    qq = np.ones([sample_size, 2])
    np.random.shuffle(data)
    qq[:, 0] = np.sort(data[0:sample_size])
    qq[:, 1] = np.sort(np.random.normal(size = sample_size))
    return qq

print qq_plot(measurements, 1000)
```

Comment: Why do you select a random sample_size subset from data and not compare random variates from your theoretical distribution of the entire size of measurements against all measurements?

Answer (score 4):

To add to the confusion around Q-Q plots and probability plots in the Python and R worlds, this is what the [SciPy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html#scipy.stats.probplot) says:

> "`probplot` generates a probability plot, which should not be confused
> with a Q-Q or a P-P plot. Statsmodels has more extensive functionality
> of this type, see statsmodels.api.ProbPlot."

If you try out `scipy.stats.probplot`, you'll see that indeed it compares a dataset to a theoretical distribution. Q-Q plots, OTOH, compare two datasets (samples).

R has functions `qqnorm`, `qqplot` and `qqline`. From the R help (Version 3.6.3):

> `qqnorm` is a generic function the default method of which produces a
> normal QQ plot of the values in y. `qqline` adds a line to a
> “theoretical”, by default normal, quantile-quantile plot which passes
> through the probs quantiles, by default the first and third quartiles.
>
> `qqplot` produces a QQ plot of two datasets.

In short, R's `qqnorm` offers the same functionality that `scipy.stats.probplot` provides with the default setting `dist=norm`. But the fact that they called it `qqnorm` and that it's supposed to "produce a normal QQ plot" may easily confuse users.

Finally, a word of warning. These plots don't replace proper statistical testing and should be used for illustrative purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

It exists now in the statsmodels package:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use bokeh

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from scipy.stats import probplot
# pd_series is the series you want to plot
series1 = probplot(pd_series, dist="norm")
p1 = figure(title="Normal QQ-Plot", background_fill_color="#E8DDCB")
p1.scatter(series1[0][0],series1[0][1], fill_color="red")
show(p1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 
import pylab 
import scipy.stats as stats
measurements = np.random.normal(loc = 20, scale = 5, size=100)   
stats.probplot(measurements, dist="norm", plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

Here probplot draw the graph measurements vs normal distribution which speofied in dist="norm"

Answer (score 1):

How big is your sample? Here is another option to test your data against any distribution using [OpenTURNS library](http://openturns.org). In the example below, I generate a sample x of 1.000.000 numbers from a Uniform distribution and test it against a Normal distribution.
You can replace x by your data if you reshape it as `x= [[x1], [x2], .., [xn]]`

```
import openturns as ot

x = ot.Uniform().getSample(1000000)
g = ot.VisualTest.DrawQQplot(x, ot.Normal())
g
```

In my Jupyter Notebook, I see:
[image]

If you are writing a script, you can do it more properly

```
from openturns.viewer import View`
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
View(g)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

def QQ_plot(data):

    # Sort as increasing
    y = np.sort(data)
    
    # Compute sample mean and std
    mean, std = np.mean(y), np.std(y)
    
    # Compute set of Normal quantiles
    ppf = norm(loc=mean, scale=std).ppf # Inverse CDF
    N = len(y)
    x = [ppf( i/(N+2) ) for i in range(1,N+1)]

    # Make the QQ scatter plot
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    
    # Plot diagonal line
    dmin, dmax = np.min([x,y]), np.max([x,y])
    diag = np.linspace(dmin, dmax, 1000)
    plt.plot(diag, diag, color='red', linestyle='--')
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    
    # Add labels
    plt.xlabel('Normal quantiles')
    plt.ylabel('Sample quantiles')
    
# Make up some dummy data and test
x = np.random.normal(loc=5.0, scale=0.5, size=1000)
QQ_plot(x)
```

[image: Example code output]

Advantages of this solution over others above are

1. Doesn't assume mean 0
2. Uses the analytical expression for the inverse CDF (instead of a sample)
3. Easy to modify matplotlib parameters as desired
4. Easy to edit to use a different distribution from scipy.stats