# Scipy: Is it possible to make qq plot with custom probability density function?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a 2d pdf function, it's a bivariate normal distribution,

[image]

I plot it `angle-wisely`, to compare with the original data that I get. That is, I turn `(x,y)` into `(r, theta)`, and then do some integration. This could be done very easily with `Scipy.integrate`

```
# Let f be the pdf
x_vals = np.arange(0, max_speed, 0.5)
y_vals_ =[integrate.nquad(f, 
                          [[x_val-0.5, x_val+0.5],[angle_radian-incre_radian/2, angle_radian+incre_radian/2]]) 
          for x_val in x_vals]
```

And I can compare `pdf` with original dataset
[image]

The problem, is that `density plot` is not enough, I also want to make a `q-q plot`. But, since the pdf is a result of integration, is it possible to do it with Scipy?

I have no idea about it. Maybe a possible solution is resort to `Sympy`. Since the parameters of `bivariate pdf` is all known, we can generate the correspoding angle-wise pdf.

Comment: Could you explain what a q-q plot is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quantile-Quantile Plot using SciPy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865596/quantile-quantile-plot-using-scipy)

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865596/quantile-quantile-plot-using-scipy

Comment: you will have to implement your distribution as class with a `ppf` method

Comment: @maxymoo, I don't really understand that example. There is not `pdf` there, just data. But what if I have a `pdf`?

Comment: so in the example they are comparing their samples with the normal distribution (`"norm"`). but you want to compare  to your custom pdf, which you will have to implement as a class that has a `ppf` method