# Draw a Quantile-Quantile Plot with a Confidence Band

Tags: plot, quantile

I  would like to do a quantile-quantile plot with an associated confidence band using python, as the one done with the QTLRel (R package) shown in this figure:

[image]

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: You can use the SciPy package of Python. Check this post for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865596/quantile-quantile-plot-using-scipy

Comment: Thanks. I saw that post before, but my issue is with the associated confidence band.